# difficulties to find and modify a subview

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview, subviews

I'm having some difficulties to obtains a reference to a subview.
Basically I have an UIView that contains a collection of custom UIViews.
What I need is to get a reference to one specific view to modified it.

I tried 2 different approaches where the first one as concept is something like:

```
for i in 1...8 {
    let myCustomView = MyCustomView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100)) // frame is with fake numbers just to write the snippet
    myCustomView.customProperty = some property
    myCustomView.image = some UIImage
    myCustomView.tag = i

    addSubview(myCustomView)
}
```

I tried to get a reference to let's say view with tag 2 in this way:

```
if let viewWithTag = self.viewWithTag(2) as! MyCustomView {
    viewWithTag.image = a different Image
}
```

I can see that viewWithTag is not nil but for whatever property I change, nothing is reflected in the app.

Another way to access the subview is something like:

```
let myViews = self.subviews.filter({$0 is MyCustomView})
let specificView = myViews[1] as! MyCustomView

specificView.image = something else
```

In this case I have myViews that contains all the subviews, specificView contains the specific view, but again nothing is reflected in the app

As a note, MyCustomView is of type UIImageView and the main container is UIView

Is my approach correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might need to *nudge* the image view into realizing it needs an update.

After setting the image, try doing a:

```
viewWithTag.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Also, consider using something other than tags to differentiate your custom image views (like how about a string property for name?), since the generic integers used in tags don't really tell you what they are being used for.